# partial match string in /bin/sh

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, busybox

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't partial match macaddress `$mac`?

```
#!/bin/sh

mac="f0:79:60:0f:d3:0e"

if [[ "$($mac)" = 'f0:79:60*' ]]
then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

As a note, I need to call `"$($mac)"` inside the if statement otherwise it will not substitute the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `$($mac)` has to be fixed to `$mac`, as Jea said before.

Also just use case statement; double brackets is <s>bash (or maybe zsh)</s> (edit: actually available since ksh; bash and zsh adopted it too) specific but shebang just say '/bin/sh', not 'bash'.

Here are two solutions:

1. Replace 1st line with `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/usr/bin/bash`, or whatever depending on your environment to clarify you are using bashism, or,
2. Just use case statement as it's the most portable alternative, like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

mac="f0:79:60:0f:d3:0e"

case "$mac" in ('f0:79:60'*)
  echo "true"
;;(*)
  echo "false"
;;esac
```

Comment: Technically, `[[...]]` is a kshism copied (with significant variations) by `zsh`, `bash`, `yash` and busybox `sh`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using BusyBox (ash shell), the problem seems to be that your script uses a construct not recognized by the shell (`[[...]]`). In addition, `"$($mac)"` should be changed to `$mac`.

Here is a corrected version that can run on BusyBox (as an alternative to the answer by tail spark rabbit ear):

```
#!/bin/sh

mac="f0:79:60:0f:d3:0e"

if [ -z "${mac##f0:79:60*}" ]
then
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
fi
```

The `[ -z "${mac##f0:79:60*}" ]` checks if the resulting string is empty when the largest possible portion of `$mac` is deleted that matches the pattern `f0:79:60*`.

Comment: In the environment i'm executing the script, "$mac" in the if statement is not expanded to the variable, $($mac) is.

if [[ "$($mac)" == 'f0:79:60'* ]] 

So even in the above case, the partial macaddress after the == is never matched.

Comment: Ok, based on the script I assumed you were using bash, where $(command) is the format for command substitution. Did you try to run the code? If it doesn't work I can update the answer.

Comment: your code works perfectly in a bash and even sh shell in a true Linux environment, however I'm running the script in a small busybox appliance which is behaving odd.

Comment: thanks for explaining. now I have modified my answer accordingly.